# When I click a button in navbar or other button it redirects me to a page called undefined but what I want to do is open a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

When I click a button in navbar or other button it redirects me to a page called `undefined` but what I want to do is to open a bootstrap modal

Explaining a little bit more I created a button on the page and when I put the `<a>` element inside the button it redirects to undefined page and I don't even have a `href` reference in there.

```
<!--button-->
<button class="au-btn au-btn-icon au-btn--blue">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>Adicionar Item</a>
</button>

<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="uploadModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myMediulModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div style="color:white;background-color:#008CBA" class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h2 style="color:white" class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Upload Items</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="additems.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <p>Name of Item:</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name of Item" name="item_name" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                    <p>Price:</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="priceinput" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" name="item_price" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                    <p>Choose Image:</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control"  type="file" name="item_image" accept="image/*" required/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" name="item_save">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for that im new here.

Comment: You only posted the modal and not the button you clicked and what js code you used to make it open the modal.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap modal hope your anchor tag looks like  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal">Open Modal</a> Example: https://jsfiddle.net/x6Lh10ba/

Comment: @SandeepModak my anchor tag looks exactly like that i edited my post so you can see my button, i dont know why it was not showing

Comment: @samura I updated now and it shows the button code.

Comment: have you added required css and js at the top inside head tag ?

Comment: Your code is working properly when I added jquery and bootstrap-3 in it. Please check this here - https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/gjctdh72/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need anchor inside button . This is the reason its not working 
:-

simply replace

```
<button class="au-btn au-btn-icon au-btn--blue">
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>Adicionar Item</a></button>
```

with

```
<button class="au-btn au-btn-icon au-btn--blue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal">
  <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i>Adicionar Item</button>
```